# Route/Travel planning tool like Rome2Rio with options for Bus/Train/Flight for China trip

Tags: china, planning

I'm planning for I and my significant other's trip to China (25-30 days). I found this tool called Rome2Rio which is very helpful but I'd love to know if there's any other similar tool to make a comparison and also to see if the data/info shown by Rome2Rio is 100% correct.

We want to travel by bus/train mainly to see around more so a tool with these 2 means of transport is more than enough.

Thank you in advance!